# Error coming string reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on authentication and authorization in JWT. But I have an error coming which do not not why.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Key").Value)),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Comment: What's your json file ? Do you initialize value in appsettings.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add code like below in appsettings.json :

```
 "JWT": {
    "Key": "fc746b61cde4f6665d3f9791446cd5395661860c0075a905ed9810b7391af467",
    "Issuer": "Comply",
    "Audience": "comply"
  }
```

In Program.cs:

```
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"]))
```

Comment: Why You put the issuer and audience Comply

Comment: @QasimAsghar Just to stay here, no meanings, you can use your  issuer and audience. The important is `key`.